# Define one JSON schema for two nearly the same instances

Tags: json, properties, schema, jsonschema

I have 2 very similar JSON objects:

```json
{
    "a": "a",
    "b": "b",
    "c": "c",
    "attr1": []
}
```

and

```json
{
    "a": "a",
    "b": "b",
    "c": "c",
    "attr2": []
}
```

Is there any possibility in draft v4 to define one schema for both of these instances?

**UPDATE:** No additional properties are allowed for both JSON instances.

Thanks

Comment: What do you want to do exactly? Please can you elaborate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you may use `oneOf` keyword to accept  `attr1` or `attr2` or use `anyOf` keyword if both could be present. For instance:

```
{
    "type":"object",
    "properties" : {
        "a" : {
            "type" : "string"
        },
        "b" : {
            "type" : "string"
        },
        "c" : {
            "type" : "string"
        }
    },
    "oneOf" : [{
            "properties" : {
                "attr1" : {
                    "type" : "array"
                }
            },
            "required":["attr1"]
        }, {
            "properties" : {
                "attr2" : {
                    "type" : "object"
                }
            },
            "required":["attr2"]
        }
    ]
}
```

Please have a look at the [official docs](http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-validation.html#anchor88) to review all possibilities.

As suggested by @Jason in the comment, if you also want to disallow additional properties, you just have to put `attr1` and `attr2` in the top level:

```
{
    "type" : "object",
    "properties" : {
        "a" : {
            "type" : "string"
        },
        "b" : {
            "type" : "string"
        },
        "c" : {
            "type" : "string"
        },
        "attr1" : {
            "type" : "array"
        },
        "attr2" : {
            "type" : "object"
        }

    },
    "additionalProperties" : false,
    "oneOf" : [{

            "required" : ["attr1"]
        }, {

            "required" : ["attr2"]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Generally it works, but allows any additional properties in the schema. When setting **"additionalProperties": false**, **"oneOf"** makes no sense.
How to exclude additional properties correctly allowing choice between _"attr1"_ and _"attr2"_ properties

Comment: @Alex-Bogdanov, all you have to do is move the "attr1" and "attr2" declarations to the top level `properties`.  Also, you should include `"type": "object"` at the top level or anything that is not an object will validate successfully.

Comment: @Alex-Bogdanov, that constraint is not included in your question. In order to update the answer with Jason 's correct comments, it would be better if you update your question.

Comment: @jruizaranguren Updated, but still the schema above validates successfully JSON objects like this:

`inst = {   
    "a": "a",
    "b": "b",
    "c": "c",
    "attr1": [],
    "d": {}
}`

Comment: @jruizaranguren, guys, this is something magnificent! It WORKS!!! I really haven't known that it is possible to handle top level properties using **"oneOf", "anyOf"** attributes in this kind of manner.
Thanks a lot for showing me it!

Comment: You are welcome. The best thank-you notes in SO are upvotes ;-)

Answer (score 0):

yes, you set attr1 to null:

```
data =   { 
       "a": "a",
       "b": "b",
       "c": "c",  
       "attr1": null
 }
```

than and based on your need you assign list or object:

`data['attr1'] = [1,2,3]` or `data['attr1'] = {"k1":1, "k2":2}`

while processing you can always test

```
if data['attr1'] is list
   do
else if data['attr1'] is object
   do
```

Comment: I guess it is more about how to define a [schema](http://json-schema.org/documentation.html) that allows both array and object as value for the property.